# Synchronise an audio to accurate transcription on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-to-text

I'm trying to synchronise text in my iOS app to audio that is being streamed simultaneously. The text is a very very accurate transcription of the audio that has been previously done manually. Is it possible to use keyword spotting or audio to text to assist with this?

The text is already indexed in the app with the clucene search engine, so it'll be very easy to search for any string of text/words in any paragraph in the text. Even if the audio to text conversion is not 100% accurate the search engine should be able to handle it and still find the best match in text within a couple tries.

Could you point me to any open source libraries for the audio to text conversion that would assist with this? I would prefer one that can convert the streamed audio to text directly and not rely on the microphones as is common in speech the text libraries as there may be cases where users may use headphones with the app and/or their may be background noise.

Comment: Not sure why do you want to do sync on iOS exactly. If your bring the manually produced text from outside, why don't you timestamp it outside too and bring text with timestamps? There are quite some solutions for timestamping.

Comment: Not only text sync but the user may choose to skip the audio file to any point, and I'll like to have the option to find the point where the audio has reached. I don't want to timestamp because its over 600 documents each 90+ pages long (pdf). Translates to 600 audio files each 4+ hrs long. Is there a way to automatically timestamp all these?

Answer (score 0):

To recognize audiofile or audiostream on iOS you can use CMUSphinx with Openears.

To recognize a file you need to set `pathToTestFile`, see for details

http://www.politepix.com/openears/#PocketsphinxController_Class_Reference

To recognize the stream you can feed the audio into pocketsphinx through Pocketsphinx API

Since you know the text beforehand you can create a grammar from it and the recognition will be accurate.